# The new drink machine

Tags: knowledge, story

At work today, they installed a new machine, it has a keyboard instead of the usual buttons to select my drink of choice. This morning, I went to take a coffee, so I typed in "coffee", and the machine displayed an error! So I kept going, this time trying with "coffees", and this time it did work, if not for the fact that the drink the machine poured me was... probably not something any human can drink without severe harm.

A Spanish colleague of mine went to it to take a glass of water, and then ran away from the office with said glass. Apparently he queried "agau" instead of "agua" and then left with his cup. What does that even mean? What's "agau" even?

And then during my lunch break! I typed in the name of a brand of cheap soda the old machine had, something sugary called "Osio", I typed it in, and a red hot glowing liquid came out! Is this even allowed? This could have killed me!

And that's where I am now, it's the afternoon and I've been thirsty since lunch, I just want a glass of water, what should I even type on this god-forsaken machine to get my water?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To get water out of this machine you should type:

> **HHO** i.e. H<sub>2</sub>O, its chemical formula (in fact, to be extra safe I recommend entering this as **OHH**, so as not to end up with any Holmium in your cup by mistake...)

As this machine works a little differently to others:

> It will break down any words you enter into a string of **Periodic Table element symbols** and produce a concoction based on the corresponding elements, which may or not be drinkable!
>
>  In the event that the typed word cannot be broken down exactly into elemental symbols, an error will be displayed.

To go over the examples:

> COFFEE produces an error, since this cannot be broken down into a valid string of symbols (the 'E' on the end is the problematic part). However, **COFFEES** can be written as **Co + F + Fe + Es** (or using C+O instead of Co, even) - an undrinkable concoction of Cobalt (or Carbon and Oxygen), Fluorine, Iron and Einsteinium.
>
>  **AGAU** = **Ag + Au** and no wonder your colleague left with his cup; it just got filled with Silver and Gold!
>
>  **OSIO** = **O + Si + O** (or using Os+I or O+S+I instead of O+Si), which can also be written as SiO<sub>2</sub>, known as Silicon Dioxide - in red hot liquid form this is essentially molten glass!

My recommendation? Buy your drinks somewhere else!

Comment: Damn, fastest solver in the west, there are even jokes! Congrats for the solve, I know it's not the most thrilling riddle, but I feel like going back to simpler things is good sometimes :)

Comment: @Auribouros Ha, just fortuitous timing today (it popped up precisely when I navigated to the site for a break while a large file was downloading...). Plus I'm [hardwired](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85980/one-night-in-baker-street) to look for this mechanism these days :) (The linked puzzle was the first one I ever set on this site!)

Comment: If Stiv wants to do so, then I'll say Osio is meant to be (FvB2, fb gur guvat gung pbzrf bhg vs onfvpnyyl ynin)

Comment: Buy your drinks somewhere else, but copy what your Spanish colleague did first to pay for it.

Comment: So… how *do* you get *coffee* from that thing?

Comment: @deceze If you just need the caffeine fix I'd recommend 8 C's, 10 H's, 4 N's and a couple of O's. Otherwise, bring your own instant and just ask for hot water!

Comment: What's the formula for *hot* water? :-3

Comment: @deceze Hang on, let me try and find the manufacturer's handbook... And probably the warranty at the same time - we probably ought to send this thing back ;-)

Comment: @Stiv careful it puts them in the right order! You wouldn't want to end up with a cup of some other random organic chemical with similar proportions of elements\

Comment: @deceze You enter "au" then sell your cup and buy coffee somewhere else.

Comment: How does it decide that "osio" is Silicon and Oxygen rather than Osmium, Iodine, and Oxygen? Or Sulfur, Iodine, and Oxygen?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin 'How' - I don't know (partly why I listed those combinations you mention in my answer as potential alternatives); that mechanic is not explained in the puzzle. However, I would suggest that the evidence that this is what it *does* do is in the description of the 'red hot glowing liquid' which is intended by the OP to reflect the appearance of molten glass.