# My angry new boss

Tags: knowledge, cipher, story

It had to happen with all the [people leaving](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115903/the-new-drink-machine) and the [confusing devices](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115989/the-new-office-printer) at work. My old boss resigned, leaving us with a new, quite peculiar replacement. He fires people, and then he hires others, all that every Monday! He also just naps at work and works there at night??? It's just so confusing!

Just look at his weekly routine:

- Monday 3am to 6am: Fire employees
- Monday 7:30pm to 10:30pm: Hire new employees
- Tuesday 4:30am to 9am: Take care of office plants
- Tuesday 7:30pm to 9pm: Print documents for meetings
- Wednesday: Absent
- Thursday 4:30pm to 9pm: Talk with office janitor
- Friday 9am to 10:30am: Sleep in office
- Friday 10:30am to 1:30pm: Weekly recap meeting

Crazy right? Some of those hours just don't make sense!

But here's the kicker, apparently the boss wants to see me! He requested I arrange a meal for both of us on Saturday! However, I don't know when, nor even what he wants to eat! If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it - I don't want to be the next to be fired next Monday...

**When, and what does my boss want to eat?**

Comment: @Stiv You're slipping. Your 15-minute average solve time for these is up!  haha

Comment: @JLee Knock, knock!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should swing by your boss's office at:

> **9:00** (a.m. to be safe...) and bring **fish soup**.

Because it turns out that your boss has been leaving you subtle clues all week. Mainly, it's irrelevant precisely *what* he's been doing - instead, what you *should* have made a note of was:

> the **start and end times** of each activity. Because when marked on a clock-face the hands can spell out **letters/numbers using [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore) flags**.

In this way, you can spell out the message:

> **FISH SOU** - I would suggest the next letter should be a 'P' to spell out a foodstuff: FISH SOUP! So you should turn up at 9:00am and expect your brunch to last until 12. (Though if that turns out to be too early, try again at 12:00 and expect an all-day soup session 'til 9:00pm, and - if *still* too early - again at 9:00pm for a late dinner!)
>
>  [image: Semaphore for FISH SOUP]

Comment: I made a small mistake in the riddle, and somehow you solved it, while this isn't the answer I had intended, it perfectly fits the current riddle. (And honestly, who else than main man Stiv to have a dinner with the boss)

Comment: @Auribouros I wonder whether you intended rot13(SVFU FBHC)?

Comment: Yeah i thought that too. Thx for introducing me to the frzncuber nycunorg

Comment: The "real" answer should've indeed been svfu fbhc, orgjrra sebz avar gb gjryir (nz be cz), which would have made the boss even *more* eccentric

Comment: @Auribouros I can accommodate that - hold on a sec, edit incoming...

Comment: Edited the riddle then!