# The new paper shredder

Tags: story

B: God, what happened here, it looks like a bomb went off...
C: That's why we're here, Inspector Bolton, this tech company had no business exploding.
B: They did acquire [a new drink machine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115903/the-new-drink-machine) recently as well as [a new printer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115989/the-new-office-printer).
C: Yes, but those didn't lead to incidents, even [the new head of the company](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116092/my-angry-new-boss) tried his best to comply with security measures.
B: So, Colonel, shall we check what happened ?
C: Of course.

[Data Scrapper v2.0 Initializing... ////////////////////////////]
[Data Recovered. Thank you for using Data Scrapper v2.0]
[Begin Playback]

Can you believe it? A new "state-of-the-art" paper shredder! They just can't stop buying gadgets in this company! But this one crowns all the gadgets we've had so far. It's voice-activated! Just earlier today, my boss said "Reopen Sesame", the shredder turned on, and then he shredded a handful of paper, and then walked away with a smug smile.

Or just an hour ago, my colleague wanted to show me you could activate it by saying anything you want! He said "Open the gates of hell!", and the shredder turned on! (He then proceeded to shred some old hall passes from his son's middle school). This thing could probably shred anything!

And I got confirmation of this, someone from HR came and threw an egg sandwich in the "paper" shredder, he then said something about "Awaken, great eldritch beast" or whatever. And, woudn't you know, the egg sandwich got turned into small filaments and bits of what it used to be!

Now's my time to use it! Uhm.. "Activate!". A-ha! It's working! Now what to shred... Let's start with some pape-

[Playback Ended]

B: Looks like he didn't read the manual for the shredder, but to think a simple error would blow up the whole building...
C: Some companies just want to watch the world burn, and some others make the world burn by using extremely complicated devices that blow up at the slightest problem.
B: But, what happened, what was the error?
C: Oh? Did you not understand how the shredder worked?
B: Well, no. **How did the shredder work, and why did it not work the last time?**

Comment: This is most likely the last one in the series, after all, no more company means no more wacky antics! Hope you enjoyed it as much as I did writing it!

Comment: Yes, such an office _is_ enjoyable... from the safety of your own home ;-)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few possible answers to this, but I think:

> The activation command must contain all the letters of name of the item you want to shred.
>  Hence "Open Sesame" would not work, and you need "RE-open" to include the R of "paper".
>  And the somewhat awkward incantation to make it accept an egg sandwich.

Comment: I guess maintenance man Stiv was in that paper shredder accident :( Congrats for the solve nonetheless!